# How to get the public IP v4 address

Tags: c#, ip-address

I'm using following code to get the ip v4 address:

```
IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(mycomputerName);
foreach (IPAddress ipaddr in ipAddress)
{
    if (ipaddr.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ipaddr);
    }
}
```

During test, I found that I will get three ip address:
192.168.241.1
192.168.200.1
10.108.150.48

The frist and Second address are my vmware network address. How to get the public ip address only?

Comment: those *are* real ip addresses - which one do you want?

Comment: maybe public ip address?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the public ip address

Comment: So you want to get the IP addresses only of specific adater types? You could loop over the result of `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`, fillter as you need and get the IP addresses of the suitable interfaces by `NetworkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call [this](http://icanhazip.com) site from web client and get your public ip.

```
 string public = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
```

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is asking.

Comment: hmm, I though he is asking public ip (real ip). Lets wait till he gets backs. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @cdev Thanks, but the computer may have limited network access.